# Problem with Mann-Whitney U test in scipy

Tags: wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, scipy

I am trying to perform Mann-Whitney test on a real data set using scipy. I extracted an example where the problem occurs. It seems that the function tiecorrect returns negative value which is the source of problem in my opinion. Here is my case

```
import scipy.stats

x = [1.] * 163 + [2.] * 81 + [3.] * 40 + [4.] * 6 + [5.] * 2
y = [1.] * 1007 + [2.] * 362 + [3.] * 99 + [4.] * 27 + [5.] * 13 # real-world example

print scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu(x,y)
```

I have successfully performed the MW test on the same case using SPSS and R but I would like to figure out how to do with in scipy.

Answer (score 5):

There might be a bug in the package, but if you store the `u` and the `prob` output separately, you'll see the `u` value, although the `prob` is missing for some reason.

```
u, prob=scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu(x,y)

u
Out[18]: 193405.5

prob
Out[19]: nan
```

You could then use the normal approximation of $U$ to get a p-value, though. For large samples,
$$z = \frac{U-m_U}{\sigma_U}$$
where $m_U = \frac{n_1n_2}{2}$ and $\sigma_U=\sqrt{\frac{n_1n_2(n_1+n_2+1)}{12}}$ has approximately a standard Normal distribution.

```
m_u = len(x)*len(y)/2

sigma_u = np.sqrt(len(x)*len(y)*(len(x)+len(y)+1)/12)

z = (u - m_u)/sigma_u

z
Out[23]: -3.2920646126227546
```

Then you can compute a p-value.

```
pval = 2*scipy.stats.norm.cdf(z)

pval
Out[27]: 0.00099454759456888472
```

Scipy might be trying to compute the direct null hypothesis distribution of $U$, but the Normal approximation should work fine given the number of observations that you have.

Comment: In my opinion, the problem is in computation of sigma_u. It is computed as sd = np.sqrt(T*n1*n2*(n1+n2+1)/12.0) where T = tiecorrect(ranked) and ranked = rankdata(np.concatenate((x,y))) The problem is that the quantity T is negative so the standard error cannot be computed.

Comment: @Lan I had the same problem and I came to the same conclusion after going through the source code. T is indeed negative and therefore the np.sqrt spits out a NaN.

Problem seems to be the tiecorrect function. I've found your [issue](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/4017) on github, seems it's still open...

Answer (score 5):

This thread is old, but for those like me who encounter this scipy bug and find themselves here -

The issue is indeed the tiecorrect function in `scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu(x,y)`

If you do not need tie correcting, the `scipy.stats.ranksums(x,y)` test works fine.

For your case:

```
import scipy.stats

x = [1.] * 163 + [2.] * 81 + [3.] * 40 + [4.] * 6 + [5.] * 2
y = [1.] * 1007 + [2.] * 362 + [3.] * 99 + [4.] * 27 + [5.] * 13 # real-world example

print(scipy.stats.ranksums(x,y))
Out[6]: RanksumsResult(statistic=3.2920646126227546, pvalue=0.00099454759456888472)
```